# Data binding cannot be added to my project

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-databinding

In my Android project, I have needed to enable the dataBinding library in module level build.gradle as below, but it gives me the error in the image. How can resolve it?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nasser.studio.multipledeletelistview"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding{
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.codesgood:justifiedtextview:1.0.2'
}
```

[image]

**Edit 1.**

I've changed the project level build.gradle to add support-v4 library, but now it throws the following error:

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2"
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: In your edit1 - the issue is in your Projects build.gradle.. in allprojects/repositories add `maven{url "https://maven.google.com"}` at the top, above jcenter.

Comment: @HB., It did not work.

Answer (score 0):

one of your 3rd party libraries or sdk you use rely on `support version 21.0.3.` Either remove it or have `resolutionStrategy` in your Gradle.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy { 
        force ....

    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated the question with your suggestions but they didn't work. Removing the "justifiedtextview" library didn't solve the problem too.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try upgrade your android gradle plugin.
2. Add `compile "com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2"` manually to your gradle file.

That should solve your problem.

Comment: Upgrading 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1' to 3.1.0 in project level build.gradle gives the connection time out.

Comment: @HB. This redundancy is on purpose to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

That's not a Databinding error, It's just saying that all your support-related libraries should use the same version. For example look at my gradle file:

```
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$libraries.googleSupportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$libraries.googleSupportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:$libraries.googleSupportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$libraries.googleSupportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$libraries.googleSupportVersion"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
```

My support library version being:

```
ext.libraries = [
    ...
    googleSupportVersion : '27.1.1',
    ...
]
```

Your issue seems to be that `compile 'com.codesgood:justifiedtextview:1.0.2'` internally is using the support library with a version different than yours. However your version is totally updated I wouldn't downgrade it just to have it match with the other, in any case you could just add a:

```
allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2"
    }
}
```

In your project gradle. You could also run `gradlew app:dependencies` in the Android Studio console, do a Ctrl+F on the output, search for that `com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2` and figure out from where is coming. (You only have one dependency for what I see, so there's not much science from where IT should be coming)

Let me know if this works for you.